# Minimal contrast between handled and unhandled flags

Tags: bug, design, css, moderator-tools

When there are multiple flags on a post, and some have already been handled, the contrast is extremely minimal between the two, and it's not easy to see the difference.

In the picture below, the VLQ flag has been handled, but the NAA has not. Can you tell?

[image]

Could we maybe get rid of the gray background, and use more clearly differentiated text for the two?